# How to closely monitor a java.util.map for certain insertions

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a problem debugging someone else's Java code in Eclipse and I have narrowed the problem down to a certain entry in a java.util.Map. At some stage, a certain key is put into the map, which is causing the problem. I have already checked all "put()" and "putAll()" calls to this map object, but haven't found the location at which the erroneous entry is created.

So, the question is: How can I monitor this Map object for insertions of a certain key? Basically, I would like the code execution to stop whenever key x is inserted or updated on this map. Is this possible?

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: When you say "already checked all "put()" and "putAll()"", do you mean you set breakpoints there? Also: what implementation of `Map` is used?

Comment: @marw Yes you can override put() and putAll() method.Write your on logic as per your requirment.

Comment: If key is mutable, its state can be changed after insertion. It can be a reason why you don't see how it's inserted.

Comment: maybe the map is already constructed with the entry in question.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel: Correct, I have set breakpoints at all put and putAll calls for this map instance. None of these set the key, but yet it is there. SpaceTrucker, the map is empty after construction.

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse you can create a conditional breakpoint. This breakpoint will only trigger when your specified condition takes place. This will allow you to monitor the `put` methods on the map.

Step 1: Select the breakpoint properties after right clicking on your breakpoint:

[image]

Step 2: Select the **conditional** checkbox and enter your condition:

[image]

Step 3: Run your app in debug mode.

Comment: I find it easier to do this in the debug perspective in the breakpoints view.

Comment: The questioner probably knows this already and would like to know exactly where to place this breakpoint.

Comment: @DaveRlz If he does know he will let me know I'm sure. From the description of his problem it sounds like a conditional breakpoint would be the best method of allowing him to check when the key is inserted into the map.

Comment: I have tried this, but not luck (even with unconditional breakpoints).

Answer (score 1):

Who does instantiate the map? If you can set it, then provide your custom implementation that throws exception if the searched value is passed. And then you will see in stacktrace, who and when insert this value.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, Leos. Thanks a lot. I have created my own class that implements the Map interface and used this instead of the default implementation. Strangely enough, though, the key with the required value is never set in the put() and putAll() methods, and yet it exists at a later stage in the code. This is really very strange...

Answer (score 0):

After speaking to one of our seniors guys, it turns out the problem was not so much the Map, bur rather an underlying XML structure that is used to populate the map. Looks like I was following a red herring. Nevertheless, thanks a lot to everyone who replied!